# arrowing hide on page load and show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working on hide and show functionality...
i have one bug in my code..
when i click the first  div...the content is opening from down to top...
at that time only the arrow should show up...
but on page load itself its showing the arrow..

providing my code below...

http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/40/

```
 <div id='firstRadio'>
        <div class="first" > First </div>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#firstRadio").click(function() {
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#secondRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#thirdRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv, #secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `arrow div` into the `content div`, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/41/

```
<div id='firstHiddenDiv'><div class="arrow-down"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit a...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css

```
.arrow-down 
       {
      display:none;
       }
```

Add setTimeout function under 'second radio' click function

```
 $("#secondRadio").click(function() {
    $("#firstHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
    $("#secondHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".arrow-down").show();
    },800);
});
```

Fiddle:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/53/)